# Downloading a Firefox extension directly to my harddrive

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, download

Is it possible to download a Firefox add-on to my computer?

How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click the `Download now` button, select `Save Link As`.
This will open a file save dialogue, which you can use to save it as you would any other file.

Answer (score 0):

With the [FEBE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2109) extension you can export a xpi file for all your installed addons, so you can just install it normally.

> FEBE (Firefox Environment Backup
>   Extension) allows you to quickly and
>   easily backup your Firefox extensions.
>   In fact, it goes beyond just backing
>   up -- It will actually rebuild your
>   extensions individually into
>   installable .xpi files. Now you can
>   easily synchronize your office and
>   home browsers.